# Find the sum of all count properties in child nodes

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following TreeJSON class.

```
public class TreeJSON
{
    public string name;
    public int count;
    public int level;
    public int sum;
    public List<TreeJSON> children;
}
```

I am trying to set sum property of parent nodes by adding the count property of all descendants
to the count property of parent. I Tried using the following recursive function but did not get the correct sum values.

```
    public static void FindSum(TreeJSON data)
    {
        if (data.children == null)
            return;

        foreach (var item in data.children)
        {
            FindSum(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in data.children)
        {
            data.sum = data.sum + item.count;
        }

        data.sum = data.sum + data.count;
    }
```

I would highly appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: Hint: All you're adding right now is zeroes. You need to add 1 somewhere to count the node itself, not just the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try implementing Breadth First Search

```
 public static int FindSum(TreeJSON node) {
   if (null == node)
     return 0; // Or throw ArgumentNullException(nameof(node)); 

   int result = node.count; // or 0 if node itself should be excluded

   if (null == node.children)
     return result; 

   Queue<TreeJSON> agenda = new Queue<TreeJSON>(node.children);  

   while (agenda.Count > 0) {
     TreeJSON item = agenda.Dequeue();

     result += item.count; 

     if (item.children != null)
       foreach (var child in item.children)
         agenda.Enqueue(child);
   }

   return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged `linq`:

```
public static int FindSum(TreeJSON node) => node.count + node.children.Sum(n => FindSum(n));
```